# webpack babel поддержка async

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

Проблема:
Собрал простейший webpack.config.js под react (babel без .babelrc)
Понадобилась асинхронная функция - надо добавить plugin для babel.

Без установки плагина 
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Обнаружил три плагина на эту тему:

```
@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-functions
@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions
```

В дальнейшем понадобятся асинхронные генераторы помимо обычно асинхронных функций.

Я где то читал что также важен порядок, в котором описываются плагины.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста какие плагины применить и в каком порядке их поставить.
Кусок моего текущего конфига для babel (включена поддержка декораторов для mobx):

```
 rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Так а зачем вам плагин? Современные браузеры и так умеют async

Comment: Как только появляется запись async function - то в консоли сразу вылетает:

firebase.js:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Решение, которое помогло:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Грубо говоря надо поставить плагин babel-polyfill

Предложенный способ в моем случае сработал.
Единственно я не понял почему ?
Google chrome и так async прекрасно принимает, видимо проблема в самом babel.

Answer (score 0):

Для async/await есть плагин `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`